# Getting undefined on passing form data to param in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, formbuilder

I am trying to pass values to `formData` from a form in my view, but when I am passing my parameters, it is showing `undefined`.

```js
    // Initialize Params Object
    let myFormData = new FormData();

    // Begin assigning parameters     
    const username = myFormData.append('myUsername', this.registerForm.value.firstname);
    const email = myFormData.append('myEmail', this.registerForm.value.email);

    //post request
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:81/save.php/', myFormData).subscribe((res: Response) => {
        console.log(res);
    },
    (err) =>{
        this.indexedDbService
            .addUser(username,email)  //  undefined , undefined
            .then(this.backgroundSync)
            .catch(console.log);
            // this.backgroundSync();
    })
}
```

However, if I try passing a hard-coded JSON object, it is taking properly.
How can I pass data from `myFormData` into the parameters of `addUser` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormData.append` is a void function, so `username` and `email` will always be `undefined` in your code.

```js
const example = new FormData();
const voidResult = example.append('foo', 'bar');
console.log(voidResult) // undefined
```

You'll need to assign those to your form values instead if you want to access them that way. Example:

```js
const { firstname: username, email } = this.registerForm.value;
myFormData.append('myUsername', username);
myFormData.append('myEmail', email);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Didn't noticed it is void function.